# Convert SQL query to Android Azure Mobile Service query

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a query that works fine in an Azure SQL database, but I'm trying to use it within my Android application and I can't get it to work correctly. It is to find any overlaps in time for bookings. Here is the SQL query with some dummy data, arrival and depart are both integers:

```
Select * from bourguestMob.tableObjectBookings
where tabObjID = 28
and day = 30
and month = 3
and year  = 2015
and ((arrival <= 1600 and depart > 1600)
or (arrival< 1800 and depart >= 1800));
```

Using the Mobile Service provided, I have to use the query as something like:

```
tableObjectBookingsTable.where().field("tabObjID").eq(tables.get(i).getId())
.and().field("day").eq(day).and().field("month").eq(month).and().field("year").eq(year)
.and().field("arrival").lt(intTime).or().field("arrival").eq(intTime).and().field("depart").gt(intTime)
```

That's what I have partially but I think some part of the query needs to be nested to be evaluated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to change the end of your query to look like so:

```
.and(field("arrival").lt(intTime).or()
  .field("arrival").eq(intTime).and().field("depart").gt(intTime))
```

It helps me to look at the oData string to check if you get it right, take a look here for some samples of complex queries:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/android/test/sdk.testapp.tests/src/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/sdk/testapp/test/MobileServiceQueryTests.java#L724